# Calling a .NET web service from java 1.4

Tags: java, .net, web-services, wsdl

I'm having an issue tying a java 1.4 client to a .NET 4.0 web service (WSDL). What's the recommenced way to do this?

I'm pretty new to web services and have been tasked with creating a web service in .NET 4.0 to be hosted in an IIS environment (a java web service wasn't an option here). I'm also locked into using java 1.4. Upgrading to a newer version of java unfortunately isn't an option here.

The .NET 4.0 web service development and deployment was a breeze, but I'm struggling with tying the java 1.4 client to it. I've done a fair amount of research and most of it shows examples of using AXIS, where a java client is paired up with a java web service and use wscompile.exe to generate the stub classes. Other findings showed examples of generating classes from the WSDL using wsimport.exe, but those classes it generates include annotations, which as I understand weren't introduced until java 5.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky and rather restrictive for you.
I think you have two main options.

First option - find an older version of one of the web service client frameworks.
There are various frameworks around, including Axis, XFire, etc - loads more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks

Second option - just make a HTTP call yourself to the endpoint. If you don't mind manipulating the XML yourself this might be the easiest option. You can use either the built in Java HTTPURLConnection (search stack exchange or google for examples), or you could use Apache HTTP client for this: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

HTH
DF

Comment: Thank you for your response @davidfrancis. I like the sound of the second option you listed and will attempt to implement that. It seems like a pretty straight forward way of doing it.

Comment: No probs! I may have some code lying around where I've done that sort of thing. If you need it, let me know as a reply to this comment and I should see it in my stack overflow inbox thing ;].

Comment: Sure @davidfrancis, I'll never turn down a code example! Thanks much!